# Is it ok to link to material of dubious legality?

Tags: support, external-links, legal

**My question in general is** whether it's ok, in an answer to a Stack Overflow question, to put **links** to pages for which there's some reason to believe (not certainty) that they might be violating some copyright or other (U.S.?) laws.

So, not patently pirate sites, but for example forum posts that quote a considerable section of a (copyrighted) book.

---

I found the following related questions on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com), which have some useful information in the answers or comments:

- [Answers that direct towards material that infringes copyright](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49427/answers-that-direct-towards-material-that-infringes-copyright)
- [Are links to copyright material allowed or not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171488/are-links-to-copyright-material-allowed-or-not)
- [Create a flag type / category for illegal content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195846/create-a-flag-type-category-for-illegal-content)
- [Possible illegal content linked on answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195834/possible-illegal-content-linked-on-answer) (this one has a title equivalent to mine, but the body of the question and the answers were a lot more specific)
- [Policy on links either directly or indirectly to pirate content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137846/policy-on-links-either-directly-or-indirectly-to-pirate-content)

I listed them because the reference might be of some help, but as far as I can tell they don't really answer this question (so you don't need to read them).

There are several others, both on meta.stackexchange and here, specifically on copyright, but they cover direct quotes rather than links.

Note that the question might have been more appropriate for meta.stackexchange, but it didn't came to my mind when I first posted it.

---

#### A specific example:

I found that a list included in a book I own ([Code Complete](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/code-complete-9780735619678)) could answer very well a part of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080184/how-do-we-shorten-long-variable-name).
Given that quoting the entire list would with high probability be a copyright violation (just my feeling, I'm not a lawyer) - and that, given how concise the list already is, it would be largely impossible to rewrite it in different words or summarize it, in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080184/how-do-we-shorten-long-variable-name#answer-47104016) I currently just put a reference to the book.

However now I tried to search the web for a sentence of that list and I found that a guy in a forum (on [dreamincode.net](https://www.dreamincode.net)) has already quoted the whole thing, along with the entire section of the book in which it is included.

I would not take the existence of that post as a proof that that section can be quoted freely by anyone, so I would still refrain from adding a plain quote to my Stack Overflow answer.
However I would like to add a link to that post, as it would be much more helpful than the current mere reference to the book.
However I'm not sure if even just putting such a link would be risky from a legal standpoint or in any case undesired on stackexchange. Thence this question.

---

I know it would help if I put here the link in question, but... err.. I don't know if I can do it!!!
Here in a meta question it might be more acceptable, if you tell me so in the comments (and possibly assume responsibility) I'll add it.
Owners of Code Complete can find the post manually by searching for an unusual-enough sentence of the 11.6 section.

---

#### Potentially relevant details of the specific example:

The author of the post does not state anywhere that he had obtained a permission to quote the book, or claim that he had otherwise the right to quote it for whatever reason.
He does reference the book, though.
A somewhat sneaky aspect is that he seems to claim that he typed that section manually, while it's almost sure that he copy-pasted it from an e-book (trying to copy a table included in the quote from my book's pdf results in one identical character-per-character to the one he posted).

That forum post was made in 2009 on a rather reputable site (https://www.dreamincode.net).
If it makes any difference, the profile of the author includes his full name and a photo of him, and he is a long-time contributor (32.000 posts) of that forum.

Comment: A lot of SO users already do this, they are just not particularly aware of it.  They'll quote something back from a book they read a couple of years ago.  From memory, expounding where necessary, contracting where possible, adding their own experience with it.  Which is the best way.

Comment: I added a list of related meta.stackexchange questions, where it didn't occur to me to search before

Comment: potentially related: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2212/is-discussion-of-techniques-for-removing-drm-permitted

Comment: The example you give would fall under fair use in the US.

Comment: @erickson It is impossible to say whether something is fair use prior to a hearing before the court as fair use is determined on a case by case basis by a judge.

Comment: @TinyGiant On the contrary, it's far, far more common for people to make fair use of copyrighted work without any hearing in court. A judge only gets involved when the copyright owner disagrees with your determination.

Comment: @erickson _you_ don't determine what is fair use. A judge is the only person who can legally determine if something is fair use or not. Usually what happens is people use something, and hope for the best. It only matters if the author of the original work makes a complaint, but saying that something is fair use without going through the court process is disingenuous at best, and legally damaging at worst.

Comment: Well it's done, I did [end up adding that link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47104016/revisions#rev-arrow-aa987b38-0d5a-4b1f-83ab-4f31966c7ef4). I hope it will be useful for someone, I sure wasted a lot more time on this than I should have.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As long as you're making a good-faith attempt to answer a question, ***try not to worry about anything else.*** If there's one thing I'd hope that folks take away from this answer, it's that.

Simply linking to something doesn't create a problem for anyone. The conscientious among us would like it if:

- Links that we establish remain permanent
- We don't pass 'SEO Juice' to shady sites by linking to them

If you're really concerned that a third-party site might be in the shady bucket, then you don't really even need to get to thoughts about possible legalities .. *will this site even be here next year?* should be the first thing popping up for you :) In 2008 / 2009 there were an abundance of sites that put Linux `man` pages into HTML format, plastered them with ads, and then got them indexed. They weren't even technically breaking any rules, but the sites just *smelled* so bad that you'd be almost embarrassed to link to it.

The experience anyone following the link is likely to have is what you should really consider first, before anything else (as search engines try to do programmatically). If it's likely to be a good experience for quite some time to come, then don't think twice about linking to it. Just make sure that your answer can stand on its own even if the link breaks, and your part is done :)

As others have noted, the concept of 'fair use' applies when quoting material from a book, so there's no rules *against* it. If we get a notice from a publisher or other copyright holder, we'll work with them - that's something that's on us to worry about.

tl;dr - Try to link to stuff that doesn't have more ads than content and seems like it will be around for years to come. Citations from books are fine as long as they're clear and aren't the majority of your answer. Answers need to be able to stand on their own if links break. Beyond that, don't worry about it, it's our job :)

Comment: Thank you. I see you're Stack Overflow's "Director Of Community Strategy", does that mean that I can consider yours an official Stack Overflow guideline on this subject (and thus, btw, accept your answer, of course)?

Comment: @gbr Tim is basically the head CM, so his word goes. I'd accept this

Comment: @Machavity Thanks, just to be sure I'll wait a few days

Comment: @TimPost just so you know, as to the "don't worry it's our job" [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195875/219378) seems to indicate just the opposite

Comment: @gbr you are misinterpreting that answer. My interpretation is that "it's our job" here means that the job is to respond to copyright infringement notices/lawsuits, and not to proactively police the content.

Comment: @gbr We don't proactively police content on the grounds of copyright. That is, we don't put any more effort into detecting plagiarism or wholesale copying than we do detecting SPAM or other forms of abuse. If we're made aware of it, we take care of it, but happening to also take care of something simply because we happened to notice it doesn't put us in any special jeopardy or standing. There's no peculiar sort of bias when it comes to what or how we prioritize the removal of content that we'd rather not host (or anything we'd intentionally turn a blind eye to). [1/2]

Comment: @gbr ... which puts us pretty far out of the reach of those types of caveats. The current 'safe harbor' default works out extremely well for us in that respect, and having extremely diligent users point out places where things don't look quite right only reinforces our position there (it doesn't weaken it). Now, if we completely replaced flagging with some kind of AI it would be a different matter. [2/2]

Comment: Thank you @TimPost. As we're at it, could you confirm whether this answer (the whole answer, not these latest comments) can be considered an official Stack Overflow guideline, as per my first comment?

Comment: @gbr Yes, this answer summarizes guidance that we've been giving folks for years. Make sure your answers don't _depend_ on external links to maintain relevancy and value, and try to link to quality (and if possible, official) sources that are likely to remain for years to come. If any content (links or otherwise) that our users ever contribute becomes a problem, it's a problem that we (the company) will need to handle - it's definitely onerous and _not_ your burden as a user as long as you're acting in good faith.

Comment: @TimPost Thanks. I mark your answer as accepted, then.  
As to my present specific problem, I'm still not 100% sure but I will add that link, I think I've been prudent enough at this point :-) . I'll make sure to stress that there is value in buying the whole book, despite the large quote I'll link to.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe you should just cite the book directly and link to the publisher's page on it. What you're talking about generally falls under [fair use](https://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/what-is-fair-use/)

> If you are commenting upon or critiquing a copyrighted work—for instance, writing a book review—fair use principles allow you to reproduce some of the work to achieve your purposes. Some examples of commentary and criticism include:
>
> - quoting a few lines from a Bob Dylan song in a music review
>     summarizing and quoting from a medical article on prostate cancer in a news report
> - copying a few paragraphs from a news article for use by a teacher or student in a lesson, or
> - copying a portion of a Sports Illustrated magazine article for use in a related court case.
>
> The underlying rationale of this rule is that the public reaps benefits from your review, which is enhanced by including some of the copyrighted material. Additional examples of commentary or criticism are provided in the examples of fair use cases.

Understand that you're going to have to add an answer as well, and not just copy a whole section as your answer. A properly cited quote, combined with a solid answer, shouldn't run afoul of any copyright laws. Understand that "fair use" is a murky term and is [largely determined by the eye of the copyright holder](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2017/11/bbc-makes-a-doc-about-bill-cosby-rape-allegations-gets-sued-over-copyright/), so I can't tell you how much copying is "too much". If the copyright holder asks SO to remove it under DMCA, they'll probably comply.

As to linking the website itself, I don't know that we can/should consider the legality of the site it's linked to since you'll have to quote it here inline ([link-only answers are considered low quality and subject to deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)). That's well outside the scope of anything here. As long as you keep to the quotation rule, you should be fine here, even if the other site gets nuked via DMCA enforcement.

Comment: [Cleaned up to extract the actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/359126/3)??? My actual question was the one I wrote, the copyright thing was just a specific example I encountered. Admittedly, "_All the existing answers to copyright questions I found here_" is misleading

Comment: @gbr I'm not trying to step on toes here. If you feel I misrepresented it feel free to roll it back, but narrowing the scope (avoids any dupe closure) and cleaning up the first paragraph seemed to help the readability of the question

Comment: I ended up doing that, re-reading the current answers it's true that for the most part they only addressed the copyright aspect, but I did mean to ask about legality in general. And even in the current answers there are some parts that cover "links to possibly legally troubling content" in general.  
I didn't agree much with the other corrections either, it's very debatable but I think it was slightly better as I put it (in that edit you missed one reference to 'other laws', btw).  
I appreciate your kindness in the comment though.

Comment: As to the dupe closure, it's not a problem at present (I wasn't able to find any question that already addressed this problem, either for copyright or other laws).
Maybe if in a few days if the answers remain mostly about copyright I'll restrict the question, to facilitate a separate one on "links to legally troubling content in general".
(btw, I'm not sure if these comments are in very good english; I hope they're understandable, I can't waste any more time on them)

Answer (score 4):

I would personally be careful about *linking* to such a site if an unreasonable part of the book is available. If someone could use said post as a substitute to actually buying the book, it's almost certainly a copyright infringement and thus not okay linking it.

However, you could quote the interesting and relevant sections of the book directly into your post, regardless if you actually own the book or not, as long as you keep Fair Use in mind.

Like Machavity said, depending on the amount quoted there is a good chance it will fall under Fair Use since you are using it for educational purposes (and not commercial, for example).

Since you would be using the excerpt as a complement to your own answer, it is likely to be considered transformative enough, since you are using said material to put your own interpretation/explanation forth.

What is also important is that you only use the parts that are actually interesting and no more than you actually *need to*.