# Is it OK to use YouTube links in a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, external-links

I've found a programming example in a YouTube video that I'm struggling to apply to my own programming challenges. Is it considered OK on SO to reproduce examples from YouTube and / or include a link to the same video?

I guess this question applies to most other external sources, but I'm asking about YouTube in particular because of the growing multitude of programming examples there.

Comment: Sounds fine to me, as long as the question is clear enough (on-topic, etc) without the link as well.

Comment: As long as the video it's clearly **supplementary information** for the question, and not necessary to understand it...

Comment: If you do it, you may receive down votes........

Comment: What you shouldn't do is ask a question like "I tried to implement the tutorial from XYZ but it doesn't work. Link to youtube, Huge code dump". But if you can ask a on-topic question about your specific programming problem and add a youtube video as additional material, then I don't see a problem.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson is absolutely right. If you post a question or an answer, you may receive votes.

Comment: It is not "better" because it is a video.  It is worse.

Comment: related: [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266909/839601)

Comment: Notice that youtube videos can be country blocked in some cases, and there is no way to know this when sharing the link

Comment: Thank you all for an enlightening discussion! I'm tempted to insert the specific code snippet as an edit, and even add the link that I had in mind. But by now I'm afraid it would only clutter the question. After all, the answers provided already cover most aspects of the question. Any thoughts?

Comment: Another problem with asking about a video or blog (or in many cases, SO post) is that it is likely poor. Even if you summarize its content to where you are stuck, if it is unclear then your question is unclear. Compare to a textbook that has been written by a person who has apprenticed & worked to get a degree & typically teaches & that has been typically been reviewed by others like that & by an editor. Moreover if you are stuck somewhere in a presentation you should be doing reasonable research, which means going to authoritative references anyway.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

For YouTube links the rules are the same as for any other external link in any post:

### The content on the other side of the link should only provide *supplementary information*, which is not required to properly understand the question.

Posts (either questions or answers) need to be **self-contained**, and do not require visiting external resources to be understood. Users should not need to visit another site (link could be dead, stale or broken; the content on the other side may be unsavoury or NSFW in some way; it could be spammy... and there is simply no way to know without actually visiting the link. Which many will reasonably want to avoid).

If removing the link makes impossible to answer your question, **then your question is liable to be closed as off-topic (and downvoted in the process).**

If removing a link makes your answer useless, it will flagged as "not an answer" and deleted.

The fact that we are talking about YouTube doesn't change the rules about links to external resources in posts.

Comment: Thank you for answering! This may be more suitable for a new question, but do you know how we should take possible copy-rights on the youtube content into consideration? On this particular video it is stated that it's under a 'standard youtube license'

Comment: Not a copyright expert. But as far as I'm aware, by linking to something you are not actually distributing copyrighted content. If you re-post code used in the video in your question, you should be mindful of copyright and licenses, read the "standard youtube licence", and try to keep the snippets short enough so that "fair use" applies. But again: I'm not an expert in the field, and that follow up is probably more on-topic on law.se than on meta.so.

Comment: @vestland Per a CM, as long as you're posting a "good faith" question or answer, [you can let SO worry about the copyright](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359133/2370483)

Comment: Also, [read this Meta.SE about link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), which is the policy yivi is referencing

Comment: It's not about being off-site, SO could implement a video-server to overcome it. I highlighted some of the major flaws of videos in questions in my answer below.

Comment: The same crap would be linked every day/week/semester, with continual 'Please explain..', 'I have confusion..', 'Doubts about..'.  It would be similar to 'ordinary' text questions but with extra delay. latency and bandwidth-waste before you can decide to downvote and closevote.  At best, it's an excuse to obfuscate bad questions.  At worst, you open some link at work, find out it's illegal porn or PHP code, your boss spots it and the cops escort you out of the building. NO THANKS!

Answer (score 40):

I would strongly advise against relying on videos to present the problem in your question, if you expect to get an answer, that is.

Video is generally a very poor resource to reproduce a problem for the following reasons:

- Videos are not searchable. This means that someone will have to watch the entire video, instead pressing ctrl-F and going directly to the part of interest.
- Videos are not always available, various policy reasons may prevent someone to watch a video. It may be technically possible to watch it, but who would go into the effort of doing it, when they can just answer the next question that doesn't rely on video.
- Videos often rely on spoken instructions, but sound is not always available, because the potential answerer may be in a room with other people (both at work and at home), and will probably not be interested in finding earphones just to answer a question.
- Videos are not easily searchable by search engines, which would mean that the next person with the same problem will probably not find your question.
- Videos are not copy-paste friendly. Am I supposed to retype the code from the video to reproduce the problem and answer the question? I expect almost nobody would do that

If it was up to me, I would completely ban all videos related to software-development everywhere on the internet, but unfortunately some people still produce such videos, thus forcing people to use them, instead of a text description.

For the people claiming that the problem is that it relies on off-site resources, this is only the smallest of their problems. If a question uses a snippet from a gist on github, an editor can simply fix the question by copy-pasting the snippet into the question. With a video, an editor would need to spend very much effort to properly transcribe the video into text to fix the question.

So **NO**, don't use videos in your question, unless there is absolutely no other alternative source.

Comment: The bullet points are quite agreeable, the rest however is too much. I don't generally resort to videos for programming things, but found them quite valuable nonetheless for things like game development or web-frontend things. Programming tasks that have a very visual and interactive result. Just like there are lots of bad videos out there, so are there lots of bad tutorials, documentation and books.

Comment: @Gimby: If it's some sort of animation, then maybe it could have value. For anything else, screenshots with explanatory text will be sufficient for most visual aspects.

Comment: I'm of two minds about this. Like Gimby, I agree with the disadvantages of videos as laid out in your bullet points, but if a question with a video follows the rules about linking, none of this matters because readers can simply ignore the video. So as long as you write a question which is perfectly understandable and answerable without the video link, I don't think there's any harm in adding in that link so that people who would like to watch it can attempt to do so. Ultimately that brings me to disagree with the main point that you should never link a video in your question.

Comment: Editors should NOT be copy+pasting from linked resources, because in general only the owner of the resource which is linked to has the right to rerelease it under StackOverflow's license.

Comment: @ user000001 "I would completely ban all videos related to software-development everywhere on the internet" Are you kidding me? Millions of people every year learn programming from online tutorial videos. Did you go to Uni? And if you did, did they only give you a textbook to read with picture here and there, or was there someone standing in front of the class giving a lecture - just like in a video? I do agree though don't use it on THIS site.

Comment: @AlfaBravo: I did go Uni, and thankfully none of the educational material was videos. That sentence was mostly an exaggeration though, caused by extreme frustration, when discovering that the only "documentation" on the library/API you want to use is a video, so instead of skimming it in 3 minutes, you have to waste time finding earphones, then going back and forth on the video to find the part of interest, and then retype the commands you need. For the people learning programming from scratch, I would still give more value in tutorials, books, and hands-on practice.

Answer (score 19):

Additional note. After deciding what you want to do based on the other answers, if you absolutely must post a video, **please** make the link to YouTube *begin at the relevant point in the video*.

You can do that with YouTube's *Copy video URL at current time* (context menu).

Then write the relevant time-code *in text*: [like so](https://youtu.be/csyL9EC0S0c?t=802) (at 13:22).

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Another point - streaming video is bandwidth-heavy.

This might not seem important to those who can watch the video on their 'free' work connection but, if you are on a mobile/tablet 3/4G link, you are probably subject to a data cap, and blowing it on an SO-linked YouTube video that stands a good chance, (going on non-video questions), of being a waste of time, can be costly.

We already get too many imgur jpegs of homework dumps, the thought of moving homework with sound is pretty gruesome:(

That, and all the other reasons given by user000001 etc.

No video by request.

Comment: It isn't like the video starts playing on its own...one would have to consciously engage with the video in the full knowledge that they'd run the risk of hitting their data cap when doing so .

Comment: Data cap hit because there was a copious amount of text in this answer.