# What should happen when a question, answer, or edit incorporates a link to a pirated work?

Tags: discussion, legal

In an edit to [one of my questions](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/15877/do-neurons-of-a-neural-network-model-a-linear-relationship-is-it-coincidence-tha), someone added a link to a pirated version of a copyrighted work.  I can't find a specific policy on this (I'm likely not using the right terms).  What should be the appropriate response?

Comment: perhaps this belongs in [AI Meta](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/) or if you are asking for overall SE then [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com)...

Comment: Many existing questions about that, type "copyright enforcement" into the search box.  Since your question will be insta-deleted when the content owner files a DMCA notice, it is wise to rollback the edit.  Like you did.

Comment: While example question belongs to some other SE site I think the question itself applies to SO as well...

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359126/is-it-ok-to-link-to-material-of-dubious-legality (Also, this question was flagged suggesting migration. If you'd like me to do that, please let me know. Otherwise, I agree with Alexei that this is perfectly on-topic here, as long as you want to discuss this in the context of Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Ah, apologies.  I didn't realize when I posted here that I wasn't on the stackexchange meta.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the "is it ok to link to...". This question doesn't discuss if the material has dubious legality at all, it rather assumes that the material is illegal and asks what to do about it, which the proposed duplicate doesn't really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the link is really to content that breaks copyright it should be removed not only from the post but also from the edit history. I don't think that can be done by rolling back the edit, so you would have to contact a mod for it with a custom mod flag. Something like: "Please delete this edit, it contains...". This should apply to any stack exchange.